# Loop through array of objects and assign parent object to each child array of object using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, loops

I have an array of object as follows. Currently there is only one object but invocations has an array of objects.

Depending on how many array of objects we have for `invocations`, we want to update the main array of objects. For e.g. if there are 2 objects in `invocations`, i want to separate those 2 invocations and replicate their parent object for both `invocations`.

This is not a regular iteration of array of objects and thats why i am not able to get the desired result. Any help is appreciated

```
const input = [
    {
        "name": "Test Data",
        "invocations": [
            { "invocationId": "123" },
            { "invocationId": "125" },
        ]
    },
]
```

```
const output = [
    {
        "name": "Test Data",
        "invocations": [
            { "invocationId": "123" },
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Test Data",
        "invocations": [
            { "invocationId": "125" },
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: `invocations` will always be single instance inside the parent object?

Comment: @Apostolos yes, i want to separate each invocations individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example non-one-liner though!

For each object inside your array, you loop through the `invocations` property array and push each object inside a temp array along with all the other properties.

Then this array is concatenated with the final array.

```js
const input = [
    {
        "name": "Test Data",
        "invocations": [
            { "invocationId": "123" },
            { "invocationId": "125" },
        ]
    },
]

let finalArray = []

Object.values(input).forEach(obj => {
  let arr = []
  obj.invocations.forEach(invoc => arr.push({...obj, invocations: [ invoc ]}))
  finalArray = finalArray.concat(arr)
});

console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
const splitInvocations = array => {
    return array.reduce((result, obj) => {
        const parentAssignedObjects = obj.invocations.map(invocation => ({ ...obj, invocations: [invocation] }));
        return [...result, ...parentAssignedObjects];
    }, []);
};
```

First, we loop through the array with `reduce`. We then `map` each invocation and return the parent object with a replaced value for the property `invocations`. We concat the reduce accumulator with the output of `map` using `spread syntax`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: By "should" do you mean you've tested it? One-liners to demonstrate code aren't a great idea btw.

Comment: That was the wrong wording on my part. You are correct regarding the oneline. Edited for clarification.